# Custom time interval in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have data in the below format

```
Date           Hour   Column01  Column02
2020-05-01     00     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     01     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     02     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     03     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     13     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     14     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     15     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     16     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     17     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     18     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     19     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     20     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     21     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     22     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     23     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     00     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     01     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     02     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     03     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     13     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     14     Value01   Value02
```

Is there a way to select the below records for each day? So, for 2020-05-01 time starts from hour 13 on 2020-05-01 and ends on hour 03 on 2020-05-02.

```
Date           Hour   Column01  Column02
2020-05-01     13     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     14     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     15     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     16     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     17     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     18     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     19     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     20     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     21     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     22     Value01   Value02
2020-05-01     23     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     00     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     01     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     02     Value01   Value02
2020-05-02     03     Value01   Value02
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: In  the expected the last row is Hour 03 which is not found in your input for '2020-05-02

Comment: Added it. Depending on how it is being recorded, the data may not always have a record for each hour. Regardless, I should be able to pick the interval from 1300 hours on day 01 to 0300 hours on day 02.

Comment: You can check my solution below updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` in `base R`.  We assume that the 'Hour' subsetting is only for 'Date' 2020-05-01'

```
subset(df1, (Date == '2020-05-01' & Hour >=13)|(Date == '2020-05-02' & Hour <= 3))
#         Date Hour Column01 Column02
#5  2020-05-01   13  Value01  Value02
#6  2020-05-01   14  Value01  Value02
#7  2020-05-01   15  Value01  Value02
#8  2020-05-01   16  Value01  Value02
#9  2020-05-01   17  Value01  Value02
#10 2020-05-01   18  Value01  Value02
#11 2020-05-01   19  Value01  Value02
#12 2020-05-01   20  Value01  Value02
#13 2020-05-01   21  Value01  Value02
#14 2020-05-01   22  Value01  Value02
#15 2020-05-01   23  Value01  Value02
#16 2020-05-02    0  Value01  Value02
#17 2020-05-02    1  Value01  Value02
#18 2020-05-02    2  Value01  Value02
#19 2020-05-02    3  Value01  Value02
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-02", 
"2020-05-02", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-02"), Hour = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 0L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 14L), Column01 = c("Value01", "Value01", "Value01", 
"Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", 
"Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", 
"Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01", "Value01"
), Column02 = c("Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", 
"Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", 
"Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02", 
"Value02", "Value02", "Value02", "Value02")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I used subset to create two temporary data frames. One for hours 13 and above and second for hours 3 and below. For the second data frame, I reduced the date by one and used rbind to combine both.

Comment: Alternatively, I can add 5 hours to my original timestamp and that should fix it as well. But thanks for the prompt response akrun

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to akrun's solution, here's the dplyr version:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
filter((Date == "2020-05-01" & Hour >=13)
       | (Date == "2020-05-02" & Hour <= 3))
```